# WLS 12C - Getting transaction is no longer active

Tags: java, jdbc, transactions, weblogic12c, jta

I have configured Non-XA datasource in Weblogic and setAutoCommit(false) where few of my procedure have commit and configured transaction time in WLS for 5000

I am getting this exception

```
java.sql.SQLException: The transaction is no longer active - status: 'Committed'. No further JDBC access is allowed within this transaction.
        at weblogic.jdbc.wrapper.JTSConnection.checkIfRolledBack(JTSConnection.java:202)
        at weblogic.jdbc.wrapper.JTSConnection.checkConnection(JTSConnection.java:214)
        at weblogic.jdbc.wrapper.JTSConnection.prepareCall(JTSConnection.java:610)

        at weblogic.ejb.container.internal.MDListener.execute(MDListener.java:451)
        at weblogic.ejb.container.internal.MDListener.transactionalOnMessage(MDListener.java:375)
        at weblogic.ejb.container.internal.MDListener.onMessage(MDListener.java:310)
        at weblogic.jms.client.JMSSession.onMessage(JMSSession.java:4855)
        at weblogic.jms.client.JMSSession.execute(JMSSession.java:4529)
        at weblogic.jms.client.JMSSession.executeMessage(JMSSession.java:3976)
        at weblogic.jms.client.JMSSession.access$000(JMSSession.java:120)
        at weblogic.jms.client.JMSSession$UseForRunnable.run(JMSSession.java:5375)
        at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:548)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:311)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:263)
```

I am getting the below error message,

```
java.sql.SQLException: The transaction is no longer active - status: 'Committed'. No further JDBC access is allowed within this transaction.
        at weblogic.jdbc.wrapper.JTSConnection.checkIfRolledBack(JTSConnection.java:202)
        at weblogic.jdbc.wrapper.JTSConnection.checkConnection(JTSConnection.java:214)
        at weblogic.jdbc.wrapper.Connection.preInvocationHandler(Connection.java:98)
        at weblogic.jdbc.wrapper.JTSConnection_oracle_jdbc_driver_T4CConnection.physicalConnectionWithin(Unknown Source)
        at oracle.sql.CLOB.createTemporary(CLOB.java:1118)
        at oracle.sql.CLOB.createTemporary(CLOB.java:1078)

        at weblogic.ejb.container.internal.MDListener.execute(MDListener.java:451)
        at weblogic.ejb.container.internal.MDListener.transactionalOnMessage(MDListener.java:375)
        at weblogic.ejb.container.internal.MDListener.onMessage(MDListener.java:310)
        at weblogic.jms.client.JMSSession.onMessage(JMSSession.java:4855)
        at weblogic.jms.client.JMSSession.execute(JMSSession.java:4529)
        at weblogic.jms.client.JMSSession.executeMessage(JMSSession.java:3976)
        at weblogic.jms.client.JMSSession.access$000(JMSSession.java:120)
        at weblogic.jms.client.JMSSession$UseForRunnable.run(JMSSession.java:5375)
        at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:548)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:311)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:263)
```

I am using the below code to insert data to a table,

```
java.sql.Clob  clobData = oracle.sql.CLOB.createTemporary(conn,
                    false, oracle.sql.CLOB.DURATION_SESSION);
```

Comment: It appears that some of your JDBC statements are not part of the transaction they have been designed to be in. Please isolate those statements and debug them to pinpoint the state of the Transaction at various points with in the execution. Posting the code will also help.

Comment: I am using non-XA datasource in a JMS application , I need to understand will it give multiple connection or sngle connection object.